# Two columns of figures in revtex4

Tags: floats, revtex

I am using `revtex4` document class and would like to place several figures in succession with the `twocolumn` option passed.

*ps.* Several questions with similar key phrases are looking for ways to include large figures in a `onecolumn` format in a `twocolumn` document setting. This is not the case here.

Consider the following MWE:

```
%!TeX program = pdflatex
%!TeX encoding = utf8
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[twocolumn,floatfix]{revtex4}

%   --------------------------- %
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%   --------------------------- %
\begin{document}
\title{Manuscript Title:\\with Forced Linebreak}
\author{Richard Prichard}%
\affiliation{Test}%
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

\lipsum[1-6]\footnote{some text to add in bib..}

\section{Figures and Graphs}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

As you can see, the figures get pushed into the third page before the second column in page 2 is filled. How can I ensure that the figures continue on in the second column in page 2?

**EDIT:**

I also have bibliography coming after this section (see MWE), and so a `\clearpage`, while it works, is not as ideal a solution.
(I also realise in this MWE, the figure gets kicked into the bibliography section -- no idea why. But it has yet to affect my main document.)

---

I should also point out that there is an `endfloats` option for the `revtex4` documentclass + `\printfigures` that can be used to simulate what I am looking for here, but the captions of the figures sometimes break across columns (figure in first column, its corresponding caption in second column), which is not at all ideal. So I would like to avoid this solution, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `clearpage` to get the images placed on page two or you add more text to the article, including using the class option `floatfix` ...

To test both possibilities just move the `%` in the following lines:

```
\clearpage
%\lipsum[1-6]
```

See the following MWE

```
%!TeX program = pdflatex
%!TeX encoding = utf8
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[%
  twocolumn,
  floatfix % <==========================================================
]{revtex4}

%   --------------------------- %
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%   --------------------------- %
\begin{document}
\title{Manuscript Title:\\with Forced Linebreak}
\author{Richard Prichard}%
\affiliation{Test}%
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

\lipsum[1-6]

\section{Figures and Graphs}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}

\clearpage % <==========================================================
%\lipsum[1-6] % <=======================================================

\end{document}
```

with the results:

[image]

or with more text:

[image]

Comment: This solution works (+1), but is not ideal. I have bibliography after the figures, which will get split from the figures after `\clearpage`. Didn't expect this to matter -- will add it into the MWE above.